# How to solve this question as two same equation arise from the given question statement?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Q.If the numerator of a fraction is decreased by 1, its value becomes 1/3. If the denominator of it is increased by 3, the value  becomes 1/3. What is the fraction?

Attempted soln:

Let the fraction be x/y.
Then According to Question,(x-1)/y=1/3 => 3x-3=y-----(1)
and x/(y+3)=1/3 => 3x=y+3-------(2)

The problem is we get the same equation from both the statements. So how do we solve the question?

Comment: Then the fraction is any $\frac {x}{3x-3}$.  Example 2/3,4/9,5/12 etc. All work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One equation with 2 unknowns have an infinite number of solutions.

There are an infinite number of fractions with this property.

Ex.  $2/3$ is one ($\frac {2-1}{3+3}$).  $56/165$ is another $55/165=56/168=1/3$.